# Using Shortcode inside string which includes html (WordPress PHP File)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I have a variable inside my php-file which includes HTML like this:

```
$content = '<div id="wrapper"><div>Lorem Ipsum</div></div>'
return $content;
```

which returns in HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

But I want to add something here:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  {HERE} <-----
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

What I want to add is not HTML yet because its a WordPress shortcode like this:

```
[image_hover target="_self" image="23162" link="/"]
```

which can be parsed with PHP echo or the *do_schortcode()* function in WordPress.

How can I put this together inside that HTML string?

```
$content = '<div id="wrapper">' . do_shortcode('[image_hover target="_self" image="23162" link="/"]') . '<div>Lorem Ipsum</div></div>'
```

because this combination is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The do_schortcode() function has to be stored in a variable before

```
$shortcode = do_shortcode('[image_hover target="_self" image="23162" link="/"]');
$content = '<div id="wrapper">' . $shortcode . '<div>Lorem Ipsum</div></div>';
return $content;
```